# Parar el bucle cuando se escriban 3 números iguales consecutivos (java)

Tags: java, bucles, while, contador

He de crear un programa, utilizando un bucle while, que al escribir tres números consecutivos iguales, salga del bucle y pare el programa. Es decir, por pantalla se vería algo así:

- Introduce un número: 3
- Introduce un número: 4
- Introduce un número: 9
- Introduce un número: 5
- Introduce un número: 5
- Introduce un número: 5
- Has escrito 3 veces el número 5. ¡Adiós!

No sé cómo indicar que el contador cont se aumente únicamente cuando son números iguales. Sé que debo guardar el valor en una variable (a), pero claro, se reinicia cada vez que el bucle empieza de nuevo. ¡Muchas gracias!

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n = 0;  
    int a;
    int cont=0;
    while (cont<3){
    System.out.println("Introduce un número:");
       n = teclado.nextInt();
       a = n;
     
    if(a==n) {
     cont++; 
    }
        
    }
    System.out.println("Has escrito 3 veces seguidas el número "+n+". ¡Adiós!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes guardar los valores ingresados para luego comprobar la frecuencia de estos, no seria útil usar un array por que no sabes cuantos valores ingresaras, para ello podes apoyarte en el uso de una lista ya que el tamaño no es estatico a diferencia de un array

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
 int n = 0;  


 List<Integer>listaNumeros=new ArrayList<>();// declaramos la lista donde se guardaran los numeros  
 boolean val=false;// usamos una variable tipo boolean

 while (!val){ //cuando el valor tome el valor de true el bucle se detendra
       System.out.println("Introduce un número:");
       n = teclado.nextInt();
       listaNumeros.add(n);// agregamos los valores a la lista
       //con el metodo frequency, comprobamos que si la frecuencia o moda de cada numero es igual a 3 nos devuelva el valor de true , necesario para detener el bucle 
       if(Collections.frequency(listaNumeros,n)==3){
           val=true;
       }
        
    }
System.out.println("Has escrito 3 veces seguidas el número "+n+". ¡Adiós!");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero el profesor solo nos permite usar while, for, if else, if else if

Comment: @MartaFR si tuvieras que ingresar 2-5-4-5-3-2-5  es necesario el uso de una lista y la respuesta aplica a ese tipo de problema. Ahora que  editaste la pregunta,  esta claro lo que buscabas y que bueno que pudiste resolverlo,saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, ya tengo la respuesta. Era simplemente cambiar el orden a la hora de asignar la variable a (para guardar el número anterior). La de dolores de cabeza que me ha dado y solo era cmabiar el orden de una asignación JAJAJA. Bueno, espero que al menos esto ayude a alguien.

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int n = 0;  
    int a = 0;
    int cont=1;
    while (cont<3){
    System.out.println("Introduce un número:");
       n = teclado.nextInt();
       
       if (a==n){
           cont++;
       }
       
       a = n;
        
    } 
    
    System.out.println("Has escrito 3 veces el número "+n+". ¡Adiós! ヽ(ಠ_ಠ)ノ");
```